# How Scanner decides to wait for user input & why it doesn't wait for input with toString?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, tostring

I was trying to capture the user input(a String) by using a Scanner object to process it further as required, while doing that I tried using a method which is not listed in standard methods of String class.

So my code looked like below :

```
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the string");
    String captured_string = user_input.toString();
    System.out.println(captured_string);
```

using .toString does not throw an error at all, but also the program does not wait for the user input.

I'm aware that using a .nextLine can solve the problem here as its a standard method defined for use in Scanner class.

Can someone please help understand, why the program does not wait for the user input ?

Comment: What does it prints

Comment: Please enter the string
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\x{2c}][decimal separator=\x{2e}][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

Comment: @Simon Please [edit] your post to include the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...while doing that I tried using a method which is not listed in
> standard methods of String class.

Every class in Java inherits a class called, [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) by default. The class, `Object` has a method called, [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) which returns a `String`. It means that if a class does not override (i.e. redefine) the method, `toString`, calling this method on its object will print what `Object#toString` returns.

> using .toString does not throw an error at all

Now that you have understood the concept of `toString`, I do not need to explain to you why it did not throw an error.

> but also the program does not wait for the user input.

You have called the wrong method for this purpose. In order to wait for input, [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has the method, [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) and the methods starting with name `next` (e.g. `nextLine`, `nextInt` etc.) as per your requirement. I suggest you spend some time studying the documentation. A sample usage will be as follows:

```
String captured_string = user_input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are required to use nextLine method because toString convert the object scanner to string that's why it prints this weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Scanner.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#toString--) method returns information about the `Scanner` object itself, not any data from the input stream you are using. See the documentation:

> Returns the string representation of this Scanner. The string representation of a Scanner contains information that may be useful for debugging. The exact format is unspecified.

When you want to read data from the input stream you have to use any `next*()` method like [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).